# Azure Custom Policy: Resource Must Not Have Unknown Tag - How?

Tags: azure-policy

For this example, there are two allowable tag names for a resource.

- Environment
- Client

I want to create a policy that evaluates a resource as non compliant if it is given a tag that is neither of the above. (Note that I want to avoid using parameters, preferring that the allowable tag names are 'burnt in' to the definition.)

I have tried the following code, however it is flagging resources as being compliant when they have a tag other than the above.

```
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "tags",
          "exists": "true"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags",
          "notContainsKey": "Environment"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags",
          "notContainsKey": "Client"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly it is allowed to create a resource with:

- no tags
- the 'Client' tag only
- the 'Environment' tag only
- 'Client' and 'Environment' tags only

All other cases must be blocked.

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "value": "[if(equals(length(field('tags')),0),'noTags',if(and(equals(length(field('tags')),1),or(contains(field('tags'),'Environment'),contains(field('tags'),'Client'))),'environmentOrClientTagOnlyExists',                                if(and(equals(length(field('tags')),2),and(contains(field('tags'),'Environment'),contains(field('tags'),'Client'))),'environmentAndClientTagsExist','atLeastOneNotAllowedTagExists' )  )  )]",
        "in": [
          "noTags",
          "environmentOrClientTagOnlyExists",
          "environmentAndClientTagsExist"
        ]
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: I should have added that for simplicity, the question is posed as just these two tag names, but in application could scale to ten or more tag names.